# Loader freeze due to heavy load?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm experiencing that my loader gets stuck when my CPU usage is high, if I'm processing a heavy json request and such. My loader uses an animation, which is the one that just stops due to the heavy load on the CPU. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Show. Your. Code. Also: Use. Instruments.

Comment: What part of my code do you want to see? The flow is, that my application gets some JSON data, and process the data into an image and draw it on a map. When that happens the CPU load jumps to 99% until done, and that is why my animation in the loader stops.

Comment: "my application gets some JSON data, and process the data into an image and draw it on a map. When that happens the CPU load jumps to 99% until done, and that is why my animation in the loader stops" Because you are doing all of that wrong, presumably. It all needs to happen off the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are networking on the main thread, or performing heavy calculations on the main thread, or both. This was always wrong, and now it is biting you by canceling your animation.

Comment: Could you link me something useful to address this? Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what "this" is. You still have not shown your code. Until you do, I have no specifics of what you are doing wrong. However, I think you'll find that what I'm saying is the heart of the problem.

Comment: It is definitely the heart of the problem, I'm not working with threads at all.